# How can i show a "saved message" inside a foreach item using Knockout js?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a foreach for editing some items.
Each item has a "Save" button. I want to show a message below the button.
How can i show this message inside the click event?
This is the html:

```
        <div id="divhorarios" data-bind="foreach: horarios">
    <div>
    <label>Fecha Ini: </label><input data-bind="value: FechaIni, datepicker: FechaIni, datepickerOptions: {dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'}" />
    <label>Fecha Fin: </label><input data-bind="value: FechaFin, datepicker: FechaFin, datepickerOptions: {dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'}" />
     <label>Nombre:</label> <input data-bind="value: Nombre"/>
    <br />
<button data-bind='click: $root.saveHorario'>Guardar</button>
    <br />
    <span data-bind="visible: showGuardado" style=" color: Green;">El horario ha sido guardado</span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

In the javascript code for the model i set the showGuardado=true but the message is not showing:

```
var HorariosModel = function (horarios) {
    var self = this;


    self.horarios = ko.observableArray(horarios);


    self.guardarHorario = function (horario) {
        $.post('/admin/horariosjsonguardar/' + idModelo, horario, function (returnedData) {
            horario.showGuardado = true;
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: you need to show the code for what you are passing in,  horarios.... I take it its not items mapped as observables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't got all the code there, but most likely you need to change it to :-

```
self.horarios = ko.observableArray([]);
ko.mapping.fromJS(horarios, {}, self.horarios);
```

which will turn all the things passed in into observables.

however, given the click handler, you actually probablly want something which handles the click on each of the array items, here is a fiddle showing the code in action :-

http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/UqFP2/

this way each button is independent and each has its own wee green message.

NOTE: I changed the datepicker to a simple input and got rid of the post just for the example...

Comment: Thanks Keith! so the cause is it is not observable? 
I dont know why, because showGuardado is a property from class Horario, and if FechaIni is observable why showGuardado is not?
i have tried to add your code after self.horarios line but it says horario is not defined.

Comment: thats because I mispelled it :)  also, as I said, you aren't showing the code for where you create the data, so I'm just guessing

Comment: I added a fiddle showing an improved solution which probably is what you want

Comment: Perfect!! with your fiddle i could fix it. I had to include the mapping plugin http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html